# Ubuntu 18.04: Cannot access microphone in lenovo Yoga C930

Tags: 18.04, sound, lenovo, microphone

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo Yoga C930. Works like a charm, super fast, except that built-in microphone does not show up in preferences:
[built-in mic missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYeyM.png)

What can I do to use internal mic?
By the way: An external mic connected via USB is working perfectly.

Comment: Any chance you've since resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is an open bug report against the Linux kernel for this issue. 
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203409

There is also some discussion here that sadly never got to the resolution: https://mailman.alsa-project.org/pipermail/alsa-devel/2018-November/142369.html

You may try to pressure Lenovo to invest their own resources to ensure they add GNU+linux support to their hardware. Here's the thread for the Yoga c930: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Other-Linux-Discussions/Linux-compatibility-with-Yoga-C930/td-p/4267325

You'll have to stick with an external mic for the time being, unfortunately.